# I implement a stack in python, however the "push" method doesn't work

Tags: python, stack

I'm still new to python, so I'm practicing implementing a stack, and I don't understand why the push method doesn't work. My code is the following:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self.size = 0

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.top == None
    
    def push(self, value):
        node = Node(value, self.top)        
        self.top = node
        self.size += 1

    def pop(self):
        assert not self.isEmpty, "Error: The stack is empty"
        node = self.top
        self.top = self.top.next
        return node.value

class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, link):
        self.value = value
        self.next = link
    

def main():
    
    stack = Stack()
    assert stack.isEmpty, "--> Error: isEmpty"
    stack.push(1)
    assert not stack.isEmpty, "--> Error: not isEmpty"  
    print(stack.pop())  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the exit:

File "c:", line 33, in main
assert not stack.isEmpty, "--> Error: not isEmpty"
AssertionError: --> Error: not isEmpty

Comment: I think you forgot to call `stack.isEmpty()`

Comment: thanks, it's true, I made the change, but the "Push" function keeps failing, reporting the following error when trying to "pop":
   File "c:", line 17, in pop
     assert not self.isEmpty, "Error: The stack is empty"
AssertionError: Error: The stack is empty

Comment: Did you also mean: `self.isEmpty()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack.isEmpty` is a function, while `stack.isEmpty()` is a function call (returning a Boolean).

*Edit: If you want an attribute `isEmpty`, declare one within `__init__()` and just make sure you update it whenever a change is made to the object. That way you can refer to `stack.isEmpty` without needing to call a function. That's more of personal preference.*

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have taken it into account, but when I get to the "pop" method, I still get the error:
   File "c:", line 17, in pop
     assert not self.isEmpty, "Error: The stack is empty"
AssertionError: Error: The stack is empty
which implies that the "push" method keeps failing

Comment: You are making the same error in that `assert` statement, you need to call `self.isEmpty()`.

Comment: omg that's right, I had some very silly mistakes in grammar. Now it works perfectly

Comment: Happens to the best of us - glad you got it working! @Eduard